# Calculations in McLain groups

Tags: group-theory, math-software, gap, infinite-groups

Is there any program in GAP or other softwares doing calculations in McLain groups and finding subgroups etc. For the McLain groups see Derek Robinson's book: A course in the theory of groups, p347 (p.361 in the 2nd edition, 1995).

Best wishes,

Ahmet Arikan

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I've added some tags which may be relevant. Also, it would be good at least to add some link to the URL where the reader may find a definition without having access to the book.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you defined the terms in your question rather than just giving a reference.